# How do you determine what SQL Tables have an identity column programmatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata, identity-column

I want to create a list of columns in SQL Server 2005 that have identity columns and their corresponding table in T-SQL.

Results would be something like:

TableName, ColumnName

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Another potential way to do this for SQL Server, which has less reliance on the system tables (which are subject to change, version to version) is to use the
INFORMATION_SCHEMA views:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: note a gotcha is that you could specify  [db name].information_schema.columns ,  but run from a different db ...  and then COLUMNPROPERTY  is running against the wrong db

Comment: It's better this way when you have other schemas: where COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME)...

Comment: I think this answer doesn't work with Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: If you are looking for a simple approach that works from SQL Server 2000 onward  look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87983/692942) by @Guillermo.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` contains infos for plain tables and **views** and I suggest to add TABLE_TYPE (joining INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) for readibility of the result set.

Comment: Modifications for SQL 2017+, also locks down to specific Database
SELECT
   [COLUMN_NAME]
   , [TABLE_NAME]
   , [TABLE_CATALOG]
FROM
   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE
   COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONCAT_WS('.' ,[TABLE_CATALOG] ,[TABLE_SCHEMA] ,[TABLE_NAME])) ,[COLUMN_NAME] ,'IsIdentity') = 1
ORDER BY
   [TABLE_NAME]

Answer (score 55):

sys.columns.is_identity = 1

e.g.,

```
select o.name, c.name
from sys.objects o inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where c.is_identity = 1
```

Comment: Note: this works for me in SQL 2008, whereas the accepted answer does not (the question asks for SQL 2005).

Comment: This answer also works with Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 30):

Another way (for 2000 / 2005/2012/2014):

```
IF ((SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N'table_name_here'), 'TableHasIdentity')) = 1)
    PRINT 'Yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'No'
```

NOTE: `table_name_here` should be `schema.table`, unless the schema is `dbo`.

Answer (score 8):

In SQL 2005:

```
select object_name(object_id), name
from sys.columns
where is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

List of tables without Identity column based on [Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87983/320427) answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE        (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 0)
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

This query seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    sys.objects.name AS table_name, 
    sys.columns.name AS column_name
FROM sys.columns JOIN sys.objects 
    ON sys.columns.object_id=sys.objects.object_id
WHERE 
    sys.columns.is_identity=1
    AND
    sys.objects.type in (N'U')
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query work for me:

```
select  TABLE_NAME tabla,COLUMN_NAME columna
from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where   COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a working version for MSSQL 2000. I've modified the 2005 code found here: http://sqlfool.com/2011/01/identity-columns-are-you-nearing-the-limits/

```
/* Define how close we are to the value limit
   before we start throwing up the red flag.
   The higher the value, the closer to the limit. */
DECLARE @threshold DECIMAL(3,2);
SET @threshold = .85;

/* Create a temp table */
CREATE TABLE #identityStatus
(
      database_name     VARCHAR(128)
    , table_name        VARCHAR(128)
    , column_name       VARCHAR(128)
    , data_type         VARCHAR(128)
    , last_value        BIGINT
    , max_value         BIGINT
);

DECLARE @dbname sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);

-- Use an cursor to iterate through the databases since in 2000 there's no sp_MSForEachDB command...

DECLARE c cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
    name
FROM
    master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE 
    name NOT IN('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb');

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'Use [' + @dbname + '];
    Insert Into #identityStatus
    Select ''' + @dbname + ''' As [database_name]
        , Object_Name(id.id) As [table_name]
        , id.name As [column_name]
        , t.name As [data_type]
        , IDENT_CURRENT(Object_Name(id.id)) As [last_value]
        , Case 
            When t.name = ''tinyint''   Then 255 
            When t.name = ''smallint''  Then 32767 
            When t.name = ''int''       Then 2147483647 
            When t.name = ''bigint''    Then 9223372036854775807
          End As [max_value]
    From 
        syscolumns As id
        Join systypes As t On id.xtype = t.xtype
    Where 
        id.colstat&1 = 1    -- this identifies the identity columns (as far as I know)
    ';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

/* Retrieve our results and format it all prettily */
SELECT database_name
    , table_name
    , column_name
    , data_type
    , last_value
    , CASE 
        WHEN last_value < 0 THEN 100
        ELSE (1 - CAST(last_value AS FLOAT(4)) / max_value) * 100 
      END AS [percentLeft]
    , CASE 
        WHEN CAST(last_value AS FLOAT(4)) / max_value >= @threshold
            THEN 'warning: approaching max limit'
        ELSE 'okay'
        END AS [id_status]
FROM #identityStatus
ORDER BY percentLeft;

/* Clean up after ourselves */
DROP TABLE #identityStatus;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for SQL 2000:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN C.autoval IS NOT NULL THEN
        'Identity'
    ELSE
        'Not Identity'
    AND
FROM
    sysobjects O
INNER JOIN
    syscolumns C
ON
    O.id = C.id
WHERE
    O.NAME = @TableName
AND
    C.NAME = @ColumnName
```

Comment: I don't know what autoval does, but it's NULL for all my identity fields.  The SQL 2000 code I have that works is 

where colstat & 1 = 1

I'm not sure where that code came from (it's about 5 years old), but my comment says that a bitmask is necessary.  But colstat = 1 for my identities.

Comment: hmm... i used status & 128 = 128 to determine my identities :-P

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using Sql Server 2008:

```
USE <database_name>;
GO
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
    , t.name AS table_name
    , c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.identity_columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @Column_Name VARCHAR(100)
SET @Table_Name = ''
SET @Column_Name = ''

SELECT  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.[Name] ORDER BY T.[Name], C.column_id ) ,
    SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id) AS SchemaName ,
    T.[Name] AS Table_Name ,
    C.[Name] AS Field_Name ,
    sysType.name ,
    C.max_length ,
    C.is_nullable ,
    C.is_identity ,
    C.scale ,
    C.precision
FROM    Sys.Tables AS T
    LEFT JOIN Sys.Columns AS C ON ( T.[Object_Id] = C.[Object_Id] )
    LEFT JOIN sys.types AS sysType ON ( C.user_type_id = sysType.user_type_id )
WHERE   ( Type = 'U' )
    AND ( C.Name LIKE '%' + @Column_Name + '%' )
    AND ( T.Name LIKE '%' + @Table_Name + '%' )
ORDER BY T.[Name] ,
    C.column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2012. 
I found that the sys.identity_columns did not contain all my tables with identity columns.

```
SELECT a.name AS TableName, b.name AS IdentityColumn
FROM sys.sysobjects a 
JOIN sys.syscolumns b 
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE is_identity = 1
ORDER BY name;
```

Looking at the documentation page the status column can also be utilized. Also you can add the four part identifier and it will work across different servers.

```
SELECT a.name AS TableName, b.name AS IdentityColumn
FROM [YOUR_SERVER_NAME].[YOUR_DB_NAME].sys.sysobjects a 
JOIN [YOUR_SERVER_NAME].[YOUR_DB_NAME].sys.syscolumns b 
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE is_identity = 1
ORDER BY name;
```

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186816.aspx

Answer (score 1):

By some reason sql server save some identity columns in different tables, the code that work for me, is the following:

```
select      TABLE_NAME tabla,COLUMN_NAME columna
from        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where       COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
union all
select      o.name tabla, c.name columna
from        sys.objects o 
inner join  sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where       c.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all columns with Identity. Modern version for MSSQL 2017+. Locks down to specific database:

```
SELECT
   [COLUMN_NAME]
   , [TABLE_NAME]
   , [TABLE_CATALOG]
FROM
   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE
   COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONCAT_WS('.' ,[TABLE_CATALOG] ,[TABLE_SCHEMA] ,[TABLE_NAME])) ,[COLUMN_NAME] ,'IsIdentity') = 1
ORDER BY
   [TABLE_NAME]
```