# How do I determine if a column is an identity column in MSSQL 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I want to do this in code, not with ALT+F1.

Comment: See also [How to identify whether the table has identity column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2871701) and [How do you determine what SQL Tables have an identity column programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/87747)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
select columnproperty(object_id('mytable'),'mycolumn','IsIdentity')
```

Returns 1 if it's an identity, 0 if not.

Comment: Just in case your table is not in the default schema (dbo), you need to specify it in the table name `mySchema.myTable`

Answer (score 25):

```
sp_help tablename
```

In the output look for something like this:

```
 Identity     Seed     Increment     Not For Replication    
 -----------  -------  ------------  ---------------------- 
 userid       15500    1             0
```

Answer (score 7):

Adjust the `WHERE` clause to suit:

```
select
    a.name as TableName,
    b.name as IdentityColumn
from
    sysobjects a inner join syscolumns b on a.id = b.id
where
    columnproperty(a.id, b.name, 'isIdentity') = 1
    and objectproperty(a.id, 'isTable') = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As expansion on @Blogbeard's answer

If you like pure query and not inbuilt functions

```
select col_name(sys.all_objects.object_id, column_id) as id from sys.identity_columns 
join sys.all_objects on sys.identity_columns.object_id = sys.all_objects.object_id
where sys.all_objects.name = 'system_files'
```

Answer (score 1):

Identity is the value that is used for the very first row loaded into the table.

There is a microsoft article which can provide good knowledge about Identity:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Now, there are couple of ways for identifying which column is an identity column in a table:

- We can use sql query: select
  *columnproperty(object_id('mytable'),'mycolumn','IsIdentity')*
- sp_help *tablename*

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server 2016 you can check if a field is identity by querying against the sys.all_columns table:

```
SELECT * from sys.all_columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName') AND [Name] = 'ColumnName' AND is_identity = 1
```