# How to identify whether the table has identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I want to find out whether the table has an identity column or not. Table is unknown to me. I have not done the structure of the table. Using Query?

I am using Sql Server Compact Edition.

Comment: See also [How do you determine what SQL Tables have an identity column programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/87747)

Answer (score 37):

```
IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1)
```

`ObjectProperty` is available starting sql server 2008  Reference: 
[OBJECTPROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx)

Comment: Warning OBJECTPROPERTY works only if executed from the database where object is located.

Answer (score 32):

This query returns a table's identity column name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetIdentity
@schemaname nvarchar(128) = 'dbo'  
,@tablename nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TABLENAME, 
             NAME AS COLUMNNAME, 
             SEED_VALUE, 
             INCREMENT_VALUE, 
             LAST_VALUE, 
             IS_NOT_FOR_REPLICATION 
    FROM     SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS 
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = @tablename
    AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = @schemaname
END
```

Then form the code side.

Call this stored procedure using the datareader role, then check `datareader.hasrows()`. If the condition value is true (`1`), then the table has identity column if set. If not then it doesn't have an identity column.

Comment: please Can u elaborate on this query? Thank u

Comment: If you are really paranoid you may also want to use:

WHERE    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = @ tablename  AND    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = @ schema

Answer (score 19):

I know it's long time ago but i found this helpful

try this :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from syscolumns where id = Object_ID(@TABLE_NAME) and colstat & 1 = 1)
BEGIN
   -- Do your things
END
```

Answer (score 16):

Any of the below queries can be used to check if an Identity Column is present in the table

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'TableName'
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE object_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM sysobjects
        WHERE name = 'TableName'
    )
```

Answer (score 7):

I would just like to add this option as well as I think it is the simplest

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TableName'),'ColumnName','isidentity')
```

Comment: I agree with @johnmcp. This option is indeed simple and returns 1 when column is identity and 0 when column is not an identity column

Comment: But it doesn't answer the OP's (and my) question, which is how to determine whether a given table has an identity column, not whether a given column is designated as the identity column. The whole point is that the table may have no identity column.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to make use of the stored procedure `sp_help`. I.e:

```
sp_help MyTable
```

This will return a DataSet that has all the information you would need on the table. There is a specific Table that has information on identities.

I.e:

If it does not contain an identity field, the Identity column will say: "No identity column defined".

Comment: I'll add that you can highlight the name of the table and then use keyboard combo ALT+F1 as short cut for this when in SSMS.

Comment: @MikeCheel doesn't work for me in ssms version 17.9.1

Answer (score 3):

@Pranay: he said Compact Edition. Stored procedures aren't supported, and there is no sys.anything.

This is the call:

`SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE AUTOINC_INCREMENT IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME='this_table'`

It will return either 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Comment: doesn't work for me - no column "AUTO_INC_INCREMENT"

Comment: You have an extra underscore

Comment: I don’t see an `AUTOINC_INCREMENT` in SQL Server 11.0.7001.

Comment: So this is specific to CE? Ah.

Answer (score 3):

...
declare  @tblhasIdentCol bit   = IF (IDENT_CURRENT( @dbName +'.'+ @schemaName +'.'+ @tableName ) IS NOT NULL , 1 , 0 )

You get numeric value if table has identity

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you (SQL Svr 2017)

Answer (score 3):

Very simple answer would be to run this:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE-NAME')
```

This would give max value of identity column if exists, if the column doesn't exist, it gives 1 as result.

Based on max value, you can identify which column is having that and determine the identity column.

Answer (score 1):

This the query that get u all the tableNames, columnnames of the table, and is_identity or not in the selected database

```
SELECT
     sys.columns.name
   , sys.tables.name
   , is_identity
FROM sys.columns
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
    AND sys.columns.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTableHasIdentity(@Tbl sysname)
RETURNS TINYINT
BEGIN 
  RETURN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@Tbl), 'TableHasIdentity')
END
```

--As simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.name as TableName,c.name as ColumnName
from sys.identity_columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like me, needed to be able to do this for tables in an arbitrary database, then I found the following solution:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [database name].sys.identity_columns AS id_col
    INNER JOIN [database name].sys.objects
        ON objects.object_id = id_col.object_id
    INNER JOIN [database name].sys.schemas
        ON schemas.schema_id = objects.schema_id
        AND schemas.name = 'schema name'
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(id_col.object_id, DB_ID('database name')) = 'table name'
) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the 1 or 0 **Boolean** Form  if the current table has identity Columns by using this

```
SELECT Count(Column_ID) FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'tableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to list all Tables with their identity column if it exists
to get you desired table add  at the end of the filter "`and o.name='TableName'`"
where Tbale Nam is the table you are looking for

```
SELECT o.[Name][TableName],i.[name][IdentityColName] FROM 
sys.objects o 
left outer join sys.identity_columns i on i.object_id=o.object_id
where o.type='U'
```