# SQL Server : how I get AUTO_INCREMENT status

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

If I have column with AUTO_INCREMENT in `person` table that was start with 1 and incremented by 2
now after I add a row in that table

I have

```
ID|Fname|Lname
---------------
1 |check|check2
3 |check3|check4
```

How in a SQL query can I get the status of the increment I mean I want to get in the SQL the value now and the increment by

In that example I want to get from the query like:

```
select 
    increment_value, increment_by 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS/sys.columns 
where 
    tablename= 'Person'
```

the result that I want to get is 3,2

if people is stuck with the same situation so

here my last code

in c#

```
    //check columns is auto incresment if yes = True or or not =False
string sql1 = string.Format("SELECT is_identity FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('{0}') AND name = '{1}'","tablename","ColumnName");
string str = DoQueryWithReturn("db.mdf", sql1);
MessageBox.Show(str[0]);


//get the ident increment Seed = start value , INCR= how many it up , Current it what number right now, last row
sql1 = string.Format(" SELECT IDENT_SEED('{0}'),IDENT_INCR ('{0}'),IDENT_CURRENT('{0}') AS Identity_Seed ", "tablename");
str = DoQueryWithReturn("db.mdf", sql1);
if(str[0].Length!=0)
MessageBox.Show(str[0]+","+str[1]+","+str[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your edit to check if a column is auto_increment (identity); you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188967/how-do-i-determine-if-a-column-is-an-identity-column-in-mssql-2000)

edit: to check the seed value; you can use:

```
IDENT_SEED ( 'table_or_view' )
```

see also: [IDENT_SEED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189834.aspx)

to check the increment, you can use:

```
IDENT_INCR ( 'table_or_view' )
```

see also: [IDENT_INCR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189795.aspx)

Comment: ty that answer my second question how i check if it increment or not

Comment: I edited my answer to include information on how to check the seed and increment for your table.

Comment: Not work for me
i try that

  sql1 = string.Format("SELECT IDENT_SEED('{0}.{1}') AS Identity_Seed", "tablename", "ColumnName");
                        str = doQuaeryWithReturn(FileName, sql1);
                        MessageBox.Show(str[0]);// return me null

Comment: You don't have to specify your column name; only your table name: 
sql1 = string.Format("SELECT IDENT_SEED('{0}') AS Identity_Seed", "tablename"); str = doQuaeryWithReturn(FileName, sql1);

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you require, try,

```
DECLARE @table varchar(50) = 'Person'

SELECT is_identity, IDENT_SEED(@table) AS Seed,
IDENT_INCR(@table) AS Increment,
IDENT_CURRENT(@table) AS Current_Identity
FROM sys.columns
WHERE 
    object_id = object_id(@table)
    AND name = 'Id' -- column name
```

Comment: i dont really know if it 2
the 2 is for example i just wanna do quary that get the column's (that is auto_increment )  status the "Seed" and the "increment"

Comment: @AsafShazar I have updated the answer to get all the fields you need

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a column is an `IDENTITY` column with this statement:

```
SELECT     
    name,
    is_identity
FROM 
    sys.columns 
WHERE 
    OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableNameHere')
    AND name = 'ColumnNameHere'
```

To find out the seed value, the increment, and the last value used, use this statement:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName = name,
    TableName = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
    seed_value ,
    increment_value ,
    last_value 
FROM 
    sys.identity_columns
```