# Finding a Identity Specification using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database, of which there is a column that has an identity specification.

However, if I do a SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME =
```

It doesn't tell me if the column is an identity specification - is there a query that will?

Comment: This question may be helpful as to what to put into your where clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sys.columns system catalog view:

```
select o.name, c.name, c.is_identity
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.type='U'
--and o.name='MyTable'
and c.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from sys.identity_columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely to be in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, which are ANSI defined, as `identity` is a SQL Server-specific feature. You could use the SQL Server-specific tables or views (depending on your version of SQL Server) like `syscolumns` / `sys.columns`.

Comment: Sure but how can I query sys.columns for a specific table when the table names are not contained within sys.columns? 

Many Thanks, 
Joel