# How can I determine in C# whether a SQL Server database column is autoincrement?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to be able to determine from the DataTable returned by DbConnection.GetSchema() whether a particular column in a SQL Server table is identity/auto-increment or not.  I cannot resort to querying the system tables directly.

Oddly, if I connect to SQL Server via ODBC, the returned datatype for such a column is returned as "int identity" (or "bigint identity", etc.) but if I use the native SQL Server driver, there appears to be no distinction between an "int" column and an "int identity" column.  Is there some other way I can deduce that information?

Comment: It doesn't look like that piece of information is available in the GetSchema() collections. Why can't you query the system catalog views?? Those would definitely hold that information!

Comment: I need a database-independent way of doing it.  It appears that querying each individual table and examining the output of the DatabaseReader.GetSchemaTable() is the only reliable way of doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataTable` has `Columns` property and `DataColumn` has [a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement.aspx) indicating auto-increment:

```
bool isAutoIncrement = dataTable.Columns[iCol].AutoIncrement
```

Comment: He needs to get it from `GetSchema()` which returns a `DataTable` with *information* about the schema, not the schema itself.

Comment: Right, I guess the assumption is that making a small query of the table to get a `DataTable` with this information is a bad idea. But if it's really coming down to it, perhaps it's not a bad idea?

Answer (score 5):

See [This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programatically)

The `GetSchema()` function will not return the info that you want. Nor will examining the DataTable schema properties. You'll have to go to a lower level and that will depend on the DBMS and likely its version.

The member below retrieves all tables with identity columns and then looks to match a specific table passed as an argument. The code can be modified to either return all the tables or the query optimized to look only for the table of interest.

```
// see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programatically
private static string GetIdentityColumnName(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Tuple<string, string> table)
{
    string columnName = string.Empty;

    const string commandString =
         "select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
       + "where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 "
       + "order by TABLE_NAME";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlConnection);
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // compare name first
            if (string.Compare(table.Item2, row[1] as string, true) == 0)
            {
                // if the schema as specified, we need to match it, too
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(table.Item1) || string.Compare(table.Item1, row[0] as string) == 0)
                {
                    columnName = row[2] as string;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return columnName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same. As far as I discovered [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/determine-if-table-has-column-autoincrement-identity-t1244313.html) "An auto increment column is implemented differently depending upon the type of database you are working with. It isn't exposed via GetOleDbSchema.".

I didn't find any other way than @kelloti mentioned. So at the moment I'm fine with this solution because at the moment I need to know if column is `.AutoIncrement`. I already have the table in memory so I don't need to query the database again.

@pesaak Please convert this answer into a comment now that you should have enough reputation.

Comment: Please move this to comment.