# How to Get correct DataColumn Properties from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using ADO.NET. When I want to save data to table in SQL I need to retrieve columns information in this table. By information I mean Column max size (I want to get `10` from `nvarchar(10)` column) and `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. 
I am using next code:

```
var selectFromCmd = SqlCommandFactory.CreateCommand("select top 0 * from [dbo]." + destTableName, SqlConnection, SqlTransaction);
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectFromCmd);
var destinationTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(destinationTable);
```

Then I get `DataColumn` like so:

```
var column = destinationTable.Columns["MyColumn"]
```

But `AllowDBNull` is always `true`

and `MaxLength` is always `-1` even if this column is `string`

So, how can I get the correct information about column properties in ADO.NET ?

Comment: why don't you try selecting the database Table Schema. here is some examples here if it doesn't help then Google is the next best thing to find what you are looking for.[GetSchema Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834592/how-can-i-determine-in-c-sharp-whether-a-sql-server-database-column-is-autoincre)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173834/ado-net-getting-the-schema-for-a-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather use the sys cataloge views for this query. Something like this....

```
SELECT  c.name ColumnName
       ,t.Name Datatype
       ,c.max_length MaxLength
       ,c.is_nullable 
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = object_id('Customers') --<-- your table name
```

Comment: That suites me the best. Thank you.

Comment: For lazy ones the whole C# code: https://gist.github.com/vkurkotov/9264c5e484c9456f4c8149fd1e4c256c