# SQL - Check if a column auto increments

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I am trying to run a query to check if a column auto increments. I can check type, default value, if it's nullable or not, etc. but I can't figure out how to test if it auto increments. Here is how I am testing for those other things:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL
AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
--AND AUTO_INCREMENTS = 'YES'
```

Unfortunately there is no `AUTO_INCREMENTS` column to compare against. So how can I test if a column auto increments?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For MySql, Check in the `EXTRA` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
    AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL
    AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
    AND EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'
```

For Sql Server, use `sys.columns` and the `is_identity` column:

```
SELECT 
    is_identity
FROM sys.columns
WHERE 
    object_id = object_id('my_table')
    AND name = 'my_column'
```

Comment: Not correct for SQL Server, since you can have an identity column which does not auto increment when identity insert is set to ON

Comment: @ChrisSim why its not correct, its working

Answer (score 11):

Assuming MySQL, the `EXTRA` column will indicate whether it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | ... |          EXTRA | ... |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|           def |   db_2_00314 | ... | auto_increment | ... |
```

And for MSSQL, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programatically/679449).

Answer (score 4):

this works for sql server:

```
    Select COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    order by TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Can you expand on how this works to solve the requester's problem?

Comment: I know slightly dated question, but for anyone looking historically and wondering, I can confirm that this solution DOES WORK if you don't want to access the sys schema.

Answer (score 4):

Run: describe 'table_name'; In column EXTRA is what you looking for

Comment: Nice and concise. Strange that you can't SELECT the Extra column, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, try this:

```sql
SELECT column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name = 'my_table'
    AND column_name = 'my_column';
```

And look for something like this (as opposed to `NULL`):
`nextval('my_schema.my_table_my_column_seq'::regclass)`