# Detecting auto-incremented keys in SQL Server -- verification

Tags: sql, sql-server

The accepted answer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772019/sql-check-if-a-column-auto-increments) says

```
SELECT 
is_identity
FROM sys.columns
WHERE 
    object_id = object_id('assignments')
    AND name = 'id'
```

tells whether the field `id` of table `assignments` is an auto-incremented field.

When i run this, i get the value `1` for the `is_identity` field. 
Does this `1` mean `true`-- "the key of this table is autoincremented"-- and is there any exception to this?

Way too new to SQL Server -- looking for verification.

//=====================

EDIT:

Added the following to the query:

```
SELECT 
is_identity,  max_length
FROM sys.columns
WHERE 
    object_id = object_id('assignments')
    AND name = 'id'
```

`max_length` is coming out as 4. `id` is of type `int`, and from what i know, `int` is up to 2^32. higher than 9999 in any case. What's missing here?

Comment: Yes, `is_identity` is a `bit` field, where 1 = yes or true, and 0 = no or false.

Comment: Also look at `sys.identity_columns`. And be careful about `assignments` vs. `dbo.assignments`. Schema is important.

Comment: thx both for the verification. 
i'll add sme more to the Q-- one thing i looked since doing something i didn't expect. maybe you can answer rather than comments this time s.t. i can accept.

Comment: An INT storage size is 4 bytes.

Comment: @JoeSwindell, yeah - 32/8, slipped. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Not much to answer here except to repeat what others have said in the comments: `is_identity = 1` means the column is auto-increment.

`MAX_LENGTH = 4` means the column is 4-byte (32-bit) wide. For character-type columns (`char`, `varchar`, `nchar`, `nvarchar`), it means the maximum length of the string.