# Determining if a SQL Server table has IDENTITY column from MS Access VBA over ODBC

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have an MS Access program that constructs a SQL `INSERT` statement that inserts rows from an Access table into a linked SQL Server table with the same table structure. The SQL Server table may or may not have an `IDENTITY` primary key.

The MS Access source table has its corresponding primary key pre-populated, and these values must be inserted into the SQL Server table for referential reasons. SQL Server won't allow this unless I toggle the `IDENTITY_INSERT` property, but to decide if I need to toggle I need to determine if there is an `IDENTITY` column in the first place.

So in VBA from MS Access I need to determine if the linked SQL Server table has an `IDENTITY` column.

This question is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programmatically/27847032) but for Transact-SQL.

I actually can get what I need using a pass-thru query, so it is feasible.

1. Create a pass-thru query to the SQL Server database.
2. In the SQL view enter

   ```
   SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'table_name'), 'TableHasIdentity') AS 'HasIdentity'
   ```

   and execute, it returns a 1-row datasheet with column `HasIdentity` that has value 1 if the table has an `IDENTITY` column.

The problem is that in VBA I cannot get at this datasheet. Given the query runs OK from MS Access I think the datasheet must correspond to a recordset and the following code should work.

```
Public Function metaODBCExecuteSQL(ByVal pstrConn As String) As Recordset

    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("ODBC Execute")
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
    qdf.Connect = pstrConn 
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N'table_name'), 'TableHasIdentity') AS 'HasIdentity'"

    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(, dbSeeChanges)

    qdf.Close
    Set metaODBCExecuteSQL = rst

END Function
```

Instead the `set rst`  line returns a run-time error 3219 invalid operation (with or without `dbSeeChanges`, which I believe is necessary for working with tables with `IDENTITY`).

Can anyone point out how I can retrieve the result set from the `SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY` query? What is wrong with my code, or is there another way.

After all if the MS Access UI can do it there must be a way.

Comment: First try this `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create and *save* the query, this works great here:

```vb
? metaODBCExecuteSQL("")(0)
' Returns 0 or 1.
```

using this function and adjusting *table_name* to some valid table name:

```vb
Public Function metaODBCExecuteSQL(ByVal pstrConn As String) As Recordset

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ODBC Execute")
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N'table_name'), 'TableHasIdentity') AS 'HasIdentity'"

    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

    qdf.Close
    Set metaODBCExecuteSQL = rst

End Function
```