# getting the value of the field if identity but not primary

Tags: sql-server

Using this query

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME[name] 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C 
ON T.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
AND T.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
```

it shows if the table has primarykey, but i want to modify this sql as if the table has no primarykey but it has an identity set as 1, return me a record so i can identify it

Comment: can you use DMVs like sys.columns, sys.tables, sys.indexes etc.?

Comment: i can but how??

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME [name]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' 
    AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
```

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/87993/3519440